# Formatting for timestamp in php

Tags: php, timestamp

I need a to create a php timestamp using this format:

2003-10-13T10:39:37.2770000-07:00

Does anyone know how? I don't even know what the "-07:00" means!

Comment: If you don't know what it means, how do you expect us to help you? I mean, it looks very like a timezone offset to me, but I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is the offset, the Timezone is in UTC format, minus 7 hours for CST time!

Comment: So, what format do you need it in?

Comment: I guess just "2003-10-13T10:39:37.2770000"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: What do you mean by PHP timestamp? How are you planning on using it?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` appears to be able to parse that format without any problems (PHP 7.1)

You could try:

```
$timestamp = (new DateTime('2003-10-13T10:39:37.2770000-07:00'))->getTimestamp();
```